# sqlite3 problems with executable .desktop file in ubuntu 16.04. LTS

Tags: python, sqlite, ubuntu-16.04

I have written a simple Python file **Example.py** like so

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c=conn.cursor()
Cursor = c.execute("SELECT position,department from STAFF")
conn.close()
```

When I run the file in a command line window

```
$python Example.py
```

it works perfectly well. After making it executable in Ubuntu 16.04. LTS with

```
$sudo chmod -x Example.py
```

and trying to open it through an **Example.desktop** file, which contains

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Example
Exec=/home/workspace/Example.py 
Terminal=False
Type=Application
Icon=/home/Desktop/Example.jpg,
```

it does not work. By interposing the opening of an image, I could track the problem to line

```
$Cursor = c.execute("SELECT position,department from STAFF").
```

Anyone an idea why this is so and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried setting: `Path=/home/workspace` in the `Example.desktop`'s `[Desktop Entry]` section as I've told you yesterday?

Comment: Yes, I did, but, unfortunately, to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, there was another bug in my code. It actually did the trick. Could you please elaborate on why this could be so for me to understand since this is more about my wish to understand computer architecture than about the concrete problem. Also, how about posting this as an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: I know that the path is there to indicate to the computer where to look for files that are called upon. I was just wondering why importing other python files from the same directory is no problem, but when an sqlite database is involved, it needs the path statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're loading your SQLite file with a relative path (sqlite3.connect('test.db')) a working directory where you execute your script from matters. When you run a `.desktop` file it executes as if you started your script from Desktop and your script looks for `test.db` there, while your actual `test.db` file is at `/home/workspace`.

To make your script execute from `/home/workspace` and therefore all relative paths to be based on it, you need to add the `Path` attribute to your `[Desktop Entry]` section:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Example
Path=/home/workspace
Exec=/home/workspace/Example.py
# etc.
```

Now when your `Example.py` runs, it runs as if you did `cd /home/workspace && /home/workspace/Example.py`, and therefore all your local paths are relative to `/home/workspace`. You can even verify you current working directory directly in Python:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

If you were executing this from your `.desktop` file without specifying `Path` it will give you your Desktop as the current working directory.

**UPDATE** - In case you're wondering why `import some_other_file` works without setting the working directory, that's because Python automatically adds the home directory of the script its executing in its `sys.path` guaranteeing that the `import` statement can search, among others, the script's home folder as well.

However, that applies only for `import` statements, it won't apply for relative paths used in file access or anything of the sort, and that's why `sqlite` cannot open the right file if you don't provide it with the path (or set the current working path to where your script resides).

If you don't want to specify working directory but still want to utilize files with relative paths, you'll have to obtain your script's path and then append your file name to it before giving the path to SQLite to open, something like:

```
import os
import sqlite3

# there are some exceptions where this will not work but for your case it's enough:
home_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))  # your script's home dir

conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(home_dir, "test.db")) 
# etc.
```

Now, in your case, `sqlite` will get an actual path to `test.db` if it is in your script's home folder, instead of just getting blank `test.db` and looking for it in the current working directory.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was just wondering why it is only with this sqlite3 call that this is necessary. If I call another python file in that directory from Example.py, it does not need the path to execute the Example.py and even retrieving function call returns from the other python file. What is special about the sqlite3 call in this instance?